# download an xml in REST

Tags: java, xml, rest

I'm trying to develop REST service which returns a list of object in XML, the objected in concerted due to JAXB annotations.
but what i'm trying to do right now is to make that returned list to be downloaded when the REST service is called.
package webService;

```
@Path( "/WebService" )
public class FeedService {

@GET
@Path( "/GetSequenceId/{id}" )
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )

// @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response showFileStoreDetails( @PathParam( "id" ) String id)
        throws ArchiveException, IOException {

    // String feeds = null;
    Sequence feedData = null;
    Liststeps listStep = new Liststeps();
    // List<attachement> listAttachementd = null;
    // File file = new File( "file.xml" );
    // Response response = null;
    try {
        /*
         * Database database = new Database(); Connection connection =
         * database.Get_Connection();
         */

        // ProjectManager projectManager = new ProjectManager();

        feedData = listStep.getSteps( Integer.parseInt( id ) );
        // listAttachementd = listStep.getAttachement();
        // StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        // Gson gson = new Gson();
        // System.out.println( gson.toJson( feedData ) );

        // feeds = gson.toJson( feedData );
        // String xml = org.json.XML.toString(gson);
        // XStream xstream = new XStream();



    } catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
        System.out.println( e );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // response=feeds;

    return Response.status( 200 ).entity( feedData ).build();

  }             
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem/question?

Comment: i want to create a folder by java code and add i also want to add the returned data inside you should know that the returned data are files not a simple text and dont care about the annotations

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate your result class with @XmlRootElement and your return type in your controller with @ResponseBody, if will become XML

Edit: That is, if you are using Spring MVC for the REST service...

Comment: i want to create a folder by java code and add i also want to add the returned data inside you should know that the returned data are files not a simple text and dont care about the annotations

Answer (score 0):

You should add @XmlRootElement to the top of your object if you are using Jackson or similar conversions
[like in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA1A9.png)

Be aware you are using @Consume with GET method and can parse parameter directly to Integer so you don't need to get String and parse to integer. Also this method will always return 200 even though there is an error.

```
 @GET
 @Path( "/GetSequenceId/{id}" )
 @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )
 public Response showFileStoreDetails( @PathParam( "id" )  int id){

   final Sequence feedData =  new Liststesp().getSteps(id);

   if (feedData == null){
       return Response.status( 400 ).entity("some error").build();
   }else{
       return Response.status( 200 ).entity( feedData ).build();
   }
 }
```

Comment: i want to create a folder by java code and add i also want to add the returned data inside you should know that the returned data are files not a simple text and dont care about the annotations